# string replace javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

```
[{"field":"Comment","message":"Message cannot be empty"}]
```

In the above string i want to replace the word **comment**. I dont wish to use any other external libraries expect jquery

Comment: Is there only one instance of the word `"Comment"` in the string or could there be many? Why don't you handle the string accordingly after parsing the JSON string into a native object, rather than performing a search and replace?

Comment: No external libraries, but you have jQuery tagged?

Comment: @Andy ~ I was just thinking the same thing. Probably easier to just manipulate a real JS object parsed from the JSON string. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you're talking about array object:

```
var array = [{"field":"Comment","message":"Message cannot be empty"}];
```

Then what you need is:

```
array[0]["field"] = "other value comes here";
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/7Xgwk/
(Click "View", click "Change" and click "View" again)

Comment: Thanks @Pranay I hope this is indeed what the OP meant. :)

Answer (score 1):

[javaScript replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Example code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Visit Microsoft!";
document.write(str.replace(/microsoft/i, "W3Schools"));

</script>
```

Comment: specific code...? dude, can you please change your name from "Web Developer" to something else...?

Comment: you can see the link give by me or if as you said you want to replace "comment" word in your string just replace "Visit Microsoft!" in my code with your code and in str.repalce fuction do the change according to it

Comment: @Pranay Rana @rochal i have already tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: @Web Developer - are you sure this is string because i can see it is a json data ...........